# handle update hibernate in multithreaded program

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I run the below code in multithreaded program and get exception:-

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ERROR: duplicate
>   key value violates unique constraint "value_pkey"

```
    @Stateless
    @TransactionAttribute(javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public class GetHelloBean{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test-unit")
        private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Hello<?> insertOrUpdateHello(Hello<?> value) {
        Hello<?> existing = null;
        try {
             existing = this.entityManager.find(Hello.class,
                    value.getKey());
            if (existing != null) {
                value = this.entityManager.merge(value);
            } else {
                this.entityManager.persist(value);
            }
            this.entityManager.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.logger.error(" value not saved : " + value.toString()
                    + " of class  " + value.getClass() + ":" + e.getMessage());
        }

        //      

        return value;
    }

}
```

Can someone explain why and how can i handle this?

Comment: please show full stack trace so we can understand where from in the code the exception was raised

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused by a race condition in your code. If two or more threads are trying to update a Hello entity with the same key, they may both have a `null` returned from find and will attempt to persist the entity. Consequently only the "fastest" of the threads will  succeed, while others encounter the constraint violation.

If `value.getKey()` is the primary key of the Hello entities, doing only a `merge(...)` should be sufficient. Hibernate will check if the entity already exists in the db or the cache and executes an INSERT or UPDATE depending on that. Concurrent executions may still yield unexpected results though (perceived out of order updates).

If it is not the primary key of the Hello entities maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998064/how-to-use-em-merge-to-insert-or-update-for-jpa-entities-if-primary-key-is-gen) can help you.